# Double iteration over 2 fields in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to display images from 2 fields of the same collection in my Meteor application. I am using aldeed's SimpleSchema and autoform like so:

```
fullwidthImage: {
  type: [String],
},
"fullwidthImage.$" : {
  autoform: {
    afFieldInput: {
      type: 'fileUpload',
      collection: 'Images'
    }
  }
},
halfwidthImage: {
  type: [String],
},
"halfwidthImage.$" : {
  autoform: {
    afFieldInput: {
      type: 'fileUpload',
      collection: 'Images'
    }
  }
}
```

As long as there are images in the arrays, I am trying to display 1 full width (FW) image then 2 half width (HW). Pretty much like so :

```
<------FW 1------>
<--HW 1 | HW 2 -->
<------FW 2------>
<--HW 3 | HW 4 -->
```

Since we cannot use *For loops* inside templates, I am having a hard time trying to figure out how I could make this work inside a helper. I thought about having only 1 image array, and loop through it, but this is not really what I want to achieve since the images will have different sizes. Nested *Each loops* would not work either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you would make it a lot easier on yourself by having a single flat list of images. you could add an additional property to the schema, like a boolean "isFullSize," and track the different sizes of images that way.

otherwise, you're looking at doing a merge of 2 flat lists, either in the publish or on the client.

if you did make it a single flat list, you could do something like this:

```
<template name="PhotoFest">
    {{#each photo in photos}}
        {{#if photo.isFullSize}}
            {{> RenderFullSizePhoto photo=photo}}
        {{else}}
            {{> RenderHalfSizePhoto photo=photo}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

the CSS would be a little tricky, but that would handle your looping.

now the hard part is getting your data in right order, something like: F, h, h, F, h, h, F, h, h (where F=full and h=half).

that's really going to depend on where that data comes from. if you're in full control, and can order it, great. you can add a field to your schema called "ordinal" of type number and just number the photos 1 through n. In your publish, you would sort it.